# Plot Columns of a Data Frame against the First Column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

In R how is it possible to plot all columns of a data frame against the first column of that data frame?

If the data frame has 4 columns, it will need be a single plot of 3 overlaying lines.

`plot(df)` produces a scatterplot matrix, while

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  plot(df$length, df[,i], type='l')
}
```

plots only the final column against the first column.

Comment: You can try `pdf('plots.pdf'); invisible(lapply(df[-1], function(x) plot(df[,1], x, type='l'))); dev.off()`

Comment: @Jota I'm on OSX running Rstudio

Comment: Do you need a single `plot`?

Comment: `ggplot(melt(DF, "x"), aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) + facet_wrap(~variable) + geom_line()` If you don't want to split the plot up like in `plot(df)`, then remove the facet_wrap part

Comment: @akrun Yes just a single plot. Updated question to reflect this

Comment: @Chris Can it be done using the base plotting function rather than ggplot2?

Comment: I very rarely use the base plot function but the engine of my code is really the melt function from `data.table` or `reshape2`. I'm sure that once the data is in htat form it would be easy to plot the different groups

Comment: It would have been better to show an example. perhaps `matplot(x= df[,1], y= as.matrix(df[-1]), type='l')`

Comment: `DF <- melt(DF, "x")`, then `plot(x = DF$x, y = DF$value, col = DF$variable)` works too

Comment: @akrun Great that works! I'll be using `matplot` and later try to convert to `ggplot2` when I'm more familiar with R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `matplot`

```
matplot(x= df[,1], y= as.matrix(df[-1]), type='l', pch=1, 
       col= 2:5, xlab='first column', ylab = 'other columns')
legend("bottomright", inset=.05, legend=c("V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), 
              pch=1, col= 2:5, horiz=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(V1 = c(12L, 21L, 50L, 71L, 98L, 135L, 147L, 178L, 
211L, 222L, 247L, 262L, 289L, 316L, 329L, 366L, 374L, 376L, 397L, 
403L), V2 = c(4L, 27L, 57L, 63L, 72L, 100L, 104L, 128L, 154L, 
156L, 169L, 179L, 194L, 200L, 238L, 247L, 277L, 303L, 331L, 370L
), V3 = c(19L, 35L, 46L, 55L, 57L, 61L, 77L, 92L, 103L, 117L, 
136L, 171L, 190L, 219L, 241L, 281L, 300L, 312L, 319L, 325L), 
    V4 = c(20L, 30L, 42L, 48L, 78L, 91L, 129L, 168L, 198L, 218L, 
    224L, 233L, 234L, 274L, 300L, 314L, 337L, 370L, 372L, 401L
    ), V5 = c(22L, 27L, 48L, 57L, 72L, 86L, 97L, 133L, 149L, 
    183L, 196L, 226L, 264L, 269L, 288L, 312L, 338L, 342L, 359L, 
    379L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```